# Adding icon covers for opera 11

Tags: opera, icons

I recently installed opera 11. I chose my web pages stored in my system to open up with opera but now no icon image comes with it. I mean the icon image is default as in when the system doesn't know with which application to open. Can anyone help me with it. It doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the icon for HTM/HTML-Pages if you have installed Opera and Microsoft Office. To solve this issue you have to delete the registry key **`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Opera.HTML`** using `regedit` and then reinstall Opera:

a. Open Start menu and enter `regedit` the start `regedit.exe` (if you are using Windows XP click "Run..." and type `regedit.exe`):

b. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Opera.HTML`

c. Select the key and delete it.

d. Reinstall Opera.

Comment: I did the same thing, except that instead of Step d., I used a [software that can restore the icon](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/), without reinstalling Opera. [(Link to related post in the Opera forums)](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=892702)